# What to replace the window.confirm function in webextensions from background pages?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

What to replace the window.confirm function in webextensions from background pages?
window.confirm its [not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#Additional_incompatibilities) in Firefox WebExtensions.

Notifications with buttons and requireInteraction [also its not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/NotificationOptions#Browser_compatibility) in Firefox.

I need a message that will not disappear unless user it is confirmed or rejected.

Maybe there is an API for this type of message? Such a kind of window with a question would be perfect:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `confirm()` into the page (depending on if it is allowed) with `tabs.executeScrip()` and handle the response.